# Convert `ls -lR` output to format of `find` output

Tags: find, format, ls, directory-listing

I need to convert `ls -lR` output to the format of `find` output

E.g. I have a text file, which is an output of `ls -lR`. The file contains:

```
/tmp/1:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 user1 ubuntu 80 May 10 21:13 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 ubuntu  0 May 10 21:13 f1

/tmp/1/2:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 user1 ubuntu 60 May 10 21:13 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 ubuntu  0 May 10 21:13 f2

/tmp/1/2/3:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 ubuntu 0 May 10 21:13 f3
```

I want to convert this file to the second one with different format, just like `find` utility uses by default:

```
/tmp/1
/tmp/1/f1
/tmp/1/2
/tmp/1/2/f2
/tmp/1/2/3
/tmp/1/2/3/f3
```

If I have the fs, which was used for generating `ls-lR`, I'll just run a `find /tmp/1`, but in my case I have no access to the original fs.

Is it possible? There must be a short perl-script for this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -ls as primary (which is slightly different from ls -l) or -exec ls -l {} +. It will however never be completely the same as ls -lR since that does different groupings and prints totals.

Actually, I think `find . -type d -exec ls -l {} +` is the closest approximation.

Comment: Your answer is for "How to generate `ls -l`-like output from find".  Thanks for pointing to `-ls` option. Unfortunatly, I have no access to the filesystem, where ls-lR was generated and my task is reverse, I just want to convert `ls-lR` output to `find`-styled output.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. In short: no. If you dump the l from the option, -R still does fancy printing grouping, which is very hard to convert to one line output from find.

Comment: It is not very hard, it can be converted with .... awk or perl. But the separate script or even programm is needed.